what does が in this sentence mean

トットちゃんは、ポカンとして、その泰ちゃんの頭が……脳味噌が、いっぱいつまっている、自分の尊敬している頭、仮分数、という仇名の頭が……見えなくなるまで見ていた。

I try to contract this sentence as follows:

トットちゃんは泰ちゃんの頭が見ていた

It seems like が in this sentence functions as an object indicator, but the object indicator in a sentence with 見る as a verb is usually を, not が.
So I don't know what role the が plays.

See https://imabi.org/the-particle-ga-%e3%81%8c-ii-object-marker/. Basically, it sometimes mark what in English would be the object of the verb.

This question is similar to: The difference between が and を with the potential form of a verb. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Isn't 頭 the subject of 見える? And the subject of 見る, トットちゃん?

I disagree with how the sentence was contracted

^ Seconding this. It needs to be（トットちゃんは、泰ちゃんの）頭が見えなくなるまで見ていた to maintain the same meaning. 頭が binds to 見える, and the whole 頭が見えなくなるまで clause adverbially describes 見る.　見る has no explicit object in the syntax (there is no 頭を), but implicitly it's understood to be 頭 again; it's just not repeated because that would be redundant/awkward. If you wanted a "fuller" sentence, you could write something like「泰ちゃんの頭が見えなくなるまで、｛それを・その頭を｝見ていた」, but the original sentence is already perfectly complete w/o that (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-drop_language). Consider also an example like「木が大きくなるまで、水をやる」.

(Btw, the shortest possible truncation here would be「（トットちゃんは）見ていた」. If you want to remove 見える, then you also need to remove its arguments along with it, so the 頭が part would follow suit. You can't remove 見える but keep 頭が; if you do, you break the sentence, as your attempt did.)

It looks like @Ody has already answered the question perfectly. So please do post it as an answer!

(Since it got the approval of a native [thanks for the feedback!], I'll be converting my comments to an answer.)

Your contraction is not correct. To maintain the same meaning, it needs to be:

（トットちゃんは、泰ちゃんの）頭が見えなくなるまで見ていた
"Totto-chan was looking at Tai-chan's head until it disappeared"

頭が binds to 見える, and the whole 頭が見えなくなるまで clause adverbially describes 見る.
If you want to remove 見える, then you also need to remove its arguments along with it, so the 頭が part would follow suit. Indeed, doing so gives you another (even shorter) valid truncation:

（トットちゃんは）見ていた

...but you can't remove 見える and yet keep 頭が. If you do, you break the sentence, as your attempt did.
見る has no explicit object in the syntax (there is no 頭を), but implicitly it's understood to be 頭 again; it's just not repeated because that would be redundant/awkward. If you wanted a "fuller" sentence, you could write something like:

泰ちゃんの頭が見えなくなるまで、｛それを・その頭を｝見ていた

but the original sentence is already perfectly complete without that (thanks to the pro-drop nature of Japanese). Consider also an example like「木が大きくなるまで、水をやる」.
